# Neo4j Performing an Avg operation on same properties across nodes linked together

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Neo4j Database which follows this form of model:

One central node for the subject. All Current Medical Data joined to it with a Current Relationship as separate nodes. If a specific node contains a medical test score and the subject has had that test before it will be joined to the score with a Previous relationship.

e.g:

```
(subject)<-[:Current]-(current_medical_score)<-[:Previous*]<-(previous_medical_score)
```

What I am trying to do is to calculate the average of this medical test and return all subject ids where the average is less than a determined cut-off point. However my request seems to only consider the value in the current_medical_score node when it performs the average operation.

```
MATCH (subject)<-[:Current|:Previous*]-(scores)
WHERE scores.MISD IS NOT NULL AND scores.MISD <> 999
WITH scores, avg(scores.MISD) as sumMis
WHERE sumMis < 4
RETURN scores.SID, sumMis;

+---------------------+
| scores.SID | sumMis |
+---------------------+
| "330"      | 2.0    |
| "2445"     | 2.0    |
+---------------------+
```

I check whether the scores MISD isn't Null or 999 as some bodies which provide data utilise 999 to signify missing data. Subject 2445 has a current MIS score of 2 and one Previous score of 8 so the expected average should be 5.0

Not 2.0

I can't quite figure out the syntax required to go through variable number of relationships and calculate the average between the values in all the relevant nodes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering this sample data set:

```
create (subject:Subject {ID:"2442"})
    <-[:Current]-(:Score {MISD:2.0, SID: "2442"})
    <-[:Previous]-(:Score {MISD:8.0, SID: "2442"})
```

You problem is you are grouping results by `score` variable. You should group by `subject` instead. That is: `WITH subject, (...)` instead of `WITH scores, (...)`

```
MATCH (subject:Subject)<-[:Current|:Previous*]-(scores)
WHERE scores.MISD IS NOT NULL AND scores.MISD <> 999
WITH subject, avg(scores.MISD) as sumMis
RETURN subject.ID, sumMis;
```

The output:

```
╒════════════╤════════╕
│"subject.ID"│"sumMis"│
╞════════════╪════════╡
│"2442"      │5       │
└────────────┴────────┘
```

Comment: Brilliant! That worked perfectly. I'll keep that in mind for future queries. Thank you very much.

Comment: As a follow-up. Whilst this does successfully calculate the average, it only does so on nodes which have a non-null or 999 value in all nodes in the chain. If there is a 999 or null value it will completely ignore that path. So if a chain has 4, 6, 999: Is it possible for it to calculate the average on just 4 and 6? Instead of completely ignoring this chain.

Comment: @GregWarren Are you sure about that? There's nothing in the query that should do that exclusion of the entire chain, just individual nodes. I just ran Bruno's query with your test dataset and it returns an average of 5 as expected. If the query was to exclude the entire chain, there would have to be a `WHERE none(node in nodes(path) WHERE node.MISD = 999)` or a `WHERE all()` with the inverse condition.

Comment: I just ran it again. The result is as expected. There are just a couple anomalies which confuse me but on the whole the queries are coming out as expected. I apologise for bringing it up. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're seeing these results is because of this:

```
WITH scores, avg(scores.MISD) as sumMis
```

Aggregation functions, like `avg()`, only have meaning with respect to the non-aggregation columns, which form the grouping key.

In this case, this line reads: "For each individual score (since `scores` here isn't the collection of scores, it's a single score, one score per record/row), find the average of that single score's MISD property". The resulting average per row is just the MISD property, since the average of a single value is the same value.

So the result of this clause is actually two rows, one for each :Score node, with MISD values of 2.0 and 8.0. Then your WHERE clause removes the row with the value of 8 (since it's >= 2), leaving you with `sumMis` of 2.0.

To ensure the `avg()` function executes for all values (instead of getting the avg of each :Score node individually, which is useless), you need to either aggregate all the scores at the same point you do the `avg()`, or remove `scores` from scope at that time.

As in Bruno's answer, removing `scores` from scope when you perform the `avg()` works. However, if each directly connected :Score node is a separate test type, and if you have multiple :Score nodes directly connected to the :Subject by :Current relationships, that query will take the average of all of them, which may not be what you want.

Ideally you would have some property for the test type, which would be the same for all the nodes in the `:Previous*` chain (but different from the other :Score nodes directly connected by :Current relationships to the subject) and you could use that as the grouping key:

```
WITH scores.testName as testName, avg(scores.MISD) as sumMis
WHERE sumMis < 4
RETURN subject.ID, testName, sumMis
```

Comment: I apologise for the late response. If I'm performing an avg operation on a specific property (like MISD) in my case it should only include the results I want. As in the data model each node contains an individual piece of data so it shouldn't include any other nodes with :Current. I appreciate the explanation on what was wrong with the logic of my original query. That really clears it up.

Comment: Glad to help! To avoid confusion, I tend to use singular nouns for my variables, except if we're actually working with lists (as in from collect(), or nodes(path), or similar), then I use plural. That helps out when you need to double-check if you're doing an aggregation correctly, you can just read out: "for each <non-aggregation columns> combination, give me <aggregation>"

Comment: I added a follow-up question to Bruno above. Whilst this does successfully calculate the average, it only does so on nodes which don't have a non-null or 999 value in all nodes in the chain. If there is a 999 or null value it will completely ignore that path. So if a chain has 4, 6, 999: Is it possible for it to calculate the average on just 4 and 6? Instead of completely ignoring this chain. And I'll apply that variable naming syntax in my future queries!